# How to get a translation vector in a certain direction? SAT

Tags: c++, mathematics, collision-resolution, separating-axis-theorem

I'm using the seperating axis thereom for discrete collision detection. I have code to find the minnimum translation vector (or distance) to seperate two shapes but how can I adjust it to get a vector in a certain direction that seperates the shapes? For example: If a box A is overaping box B 10 pixels horizontaly and 40 pixels vertically the MTV would calculate to move the box horizontally 10 px or so but I want to seperate the boxes vertically (move 40px up). How can I adjust my code to calculate a MTV in a direction of my choosing?

```
    const Vector2 ShapeImpl::CalcDisplacement(const AxesVec &axes, const Shape &a, const Shape &b) const
{
    Vector2 displacement;
    Precision_t Overlap = std::numeric_limits<Precision_t>::infinity();
    Axis smallest;

    for (auto && axis : axes)
    {
        const Projection pA = b.Project(axis);
        const Projection pB = a.Project(axis);

        // No Collision
        if (!pA.IsOverlap(pB))
            return Vector2(0, 0);

        else
        {
            const Precision_t o = pA.GetOverlap(pB);

            if (std::abs(o) < std::abs(Overlap))
            {
                Overlap = o;
                smallest = axis;
            }
        }

}

    displacement = smallest * Overlap;

    return displacement;
}
```

Comment: Do you only have boxes?

Comment: no. I have convex shapes

Answer (score 1):

When you know there's a collision, you can just use an arbitary axis (e.g. (0, 1) if you want to separate them upwards), then project the points onto this axis. The distance you need to move the objects to separate them in this direction is the overlap between the projections.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt seem to work. I'm proabably doing it wrong but not sure.

Comment: @GregWilliamson What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It returned a vector with the wrong magnitude.

Comment: @GregWilliamson Can you link a pastebin?

Comment: Extracting only the releveant parts into a pastebin would take me days.